# Using google assistant SDK with raw text as user input

Tags: google-assistant-sdk, google-assist-api

I am currently working on a project that uses the Google Assistant SDK with Python. I have it working with direct audio listening, but I want to know if there is a way to use it with raw text input instead of listening to audio.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is, apparently, a common request - but there is no way to do it yet. (Given this is still an early Developer Preview, and there have been many requests for this, we can hope they'll deliver it as part of a forthcoming update.)